# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid || Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception

I got an error in Unity saying: 
**"InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Tile.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Tiles/Tile.cs:38)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)"**
To be more precise, it complains about this line(38):
> **if (OccupiedUnit.Faction == Faction.Hero) UnitManager.Instance.SetSelectedHero((BaseHero)OccupiedUnit);**
I recently started learning Unity so I have no Idea how to fix that.
Attached the code below:

```
    if (OccupiedUnit != null)
    {
        if (OccupiedUnit.Faction == Faction.Hero) UnitManager.Instance.SetSelectedHero((BaseHero)OccupiedUnit);
        else
        {
            if(UnitManager.Instance.SelectedHero != null)
            {
                var enemy = (BaseEnemy)OccupiedUnit;
                Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
                UnitManager.Instance.SetSelectedHero(null);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
       if (UnitManager.Instance.SelectedHero != null)
        {
            SetUnit(UnitManager.Instance.SelectedHero);
            UnitManager.Instance.SetSelectedHero(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `OccupiedUnit` mustn't reference a `BaseHero` instance when your code runs.

Comment: Whatever `OccupiedUnit` is, it's not a `BaseHero` (but at least it's not null).

Comment: `OccupiedUnit` is a variable of BaseUnit type. In turn, the type `BaseHero` is inheriting from `BaseUnit` so explicit type cast is required to send it as a parameter in function that accepts `BaseHero` type. 
Class `UnitManager` stores variable of `BaseHero` type we need to work with but class Tile can only store common type for `BaseHero` and `BaseEnemy`. 
This should clarify the situation if I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Accidently I found a way to fix that. For some reason explicit type cast in the form of `SetSelectedHero((BaseHero)OccupiedUnit)` didn't work but when I changed it to `SetSelectedHero(OccupiedUnit as BaseHero)` it started to work properly.
 Don't know why it works this way but if someone has an idea I would be grateful if you could share your knowledge.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's not "working properly" - instead, it'll be passing `null` as the argument to `SetSelectedHero` whenever the concrete type of `OccupiedUnit` isn't `BaseHero` or a subclass.

Comment: It may be a Unity bug cause the same code I sent to my friend works perfect even with `SetSelectedHero((BaseHero)OccupiedUnit)`

Comment: In general, you should assume that the bug is in *your* code rather than a platform used by thousands of other developers. I suggest that you run the code in the debugger, and when the exception is thrown, look at the *actual* type of `OccupiedUnit`.

Comment: I checked how the code works with the debugger and `OccupiedUnit` holds the right object. I think I understood why the error occurred. When I restarted Unity I needed to select the `Faction` in the unit prefabs again. And when I changed enemy prefab faction to "Hero" Unity started to throw the same excpeption again. I think that was stupid mistake from me. I'm deeply sorry that due to such a stupid mistake I created a discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

GemuSenYou When you use SetSelectedHero((BaseHero)OccupiedUnit) and it fails, it will throw InvalidCastException, but with SetSelectedHero(OccupiedUnit as BaseHero), if it fails the result will be null, which you probably check somewhere in the code. That's my best quess :)

Comment: I assume that the reason for the disappearance of the problem was not the fact that I changed formulation of type cast but the fact that I restarted Unity. I commented above that I sent package with code and other files to my friend and it worked on his computer without problems.